# Making formulas to somehow automate my data binding in a inventory system

Tags: excel, inventory

I wanna extract some specific values in a string
For example, in the table below, i wanna automate the extraction of Unit of Measure and Pack Size based on the data on ITEM column.

| ITEM | Unit of Measure | Pack Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BRAND A 2X6X150ML | ML | 150 |
| BRAND B 4X3X25G | G | 25 |
| BRAND C 12X30ML | ML | 30 |
| BRAND D 12X1.5L | L | 1.5 |

Specifically, i want to automate the Pack Size column to fetch the numeric values after the non-numeric value from the right.

I have tried using RIGHT function for this instance. I somehow fetched and automate the values in the Unit of Measure correctly using right(cell, 2) but i need to do some data cleaning because single characters like G and L arent 2 characters.

Answer (score 0):

This formula works for your data set. It extracts everything after the last X in the Item and removes the *Unit of Measure* text as it is specified in the second column.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"X","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"X",""))),1)),B2,"")+0
```

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Edit: Some cells gives error

Comment: Well, you can see in the screenshot that the values you provided don't give an error. So, which value gives an error? add that to your data sample in your question and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

With O365 you have the following approach in cell `C1`:

```
=LET(x, TEXTAFTER(A2:A5,"X", -1), size, TEXTSPLIT(x, {"ML","G","ML","L"}),
 unit, SUBSTITUTE(x, size, ""), VSTACK({"Unit of Measure","Pack Size"},
   HSTACK(unit, size)))
```

Here is the output, it generates the header, and extract the unit of measure and the pack size, spilling the entire output at once:

[image: excel output]

It assumes the information to find comes after the first `X` character in reverse order. If you want the pack size as numeric, then replace `size` inside `HSTACK` with: `1*size`.